# URL rewrite conflicts in blog post by category and tags in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am developing website which there are blog posts. I wrote the clean url for the detail page of the blog posts (single blog page) by category and tags. There are conflicting with url rewrite rules. I am not good at url rewriting and htaccess. Please help me about my conflicting rules.

It works well for blog post detail page by category. but It shows like that in url for detail page by tags => https://example.com/trends-detail/113/94.php/en/94/top-10-famous-athletes-on-facebook/en/1
Another thing is not working for pagination. I have previous and next post pagination in detail page. It does not show for the pagination link by category and tags. It works only for all post pagination link. Thanks.

These are my conflict url rewrite rules:

```
#detail page for all trend blog posts
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+trends-detail\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\&title=([^\s&]+)\&lang=([^\s&]+)\&page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /trends-detail/%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^trends-detail/([^/.]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$ trends-detail.php?id=$1&title=$2&lang=$3&page=$4 [QSA,NC]

#detail page for trend blog posts by category
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+trends-detail\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\&catid=([^\s&]+)\&title=([^\s&]+)\&lang=([^\s&]+)\&catpage=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /trends-detail/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^trends-detail/([^/.]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /trends-detail.php?id=$1&catid=$2&title=$3&lang=$4&catpage=$5 [QSA,NC]

#detail page for trend blog posts by tags
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+trends-detail\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\&tagid=([^\s&]+)\&title=([^\s&]+)\&lang=([^\s&]+)\&tagpage=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /trends-detail/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^trends-detail/([^/.]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$ trends-detail.php?id=$1&tagid=$2&title=$3&lang=$4&tagpage=$5 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: `.*` matches _anything_, including a slash. So `^trends-detail/([^/.]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$` will already match anything, that you try to match later on with `^trends-detail/([^/.]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$`. The rule of thumb is - always order your stuff from most to least specific.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your answer. Can you explain me with the example code for that? What should I do the order and matchs?. Because I have less understanding and no experience in url rewrite.